# How to use AWS Cognito with cookie sessions?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito, session-cookies

I have read this article:[Stop using JWTs!](https://gist.github.com/samsch/0d1f3d3b4745d778f78b230cf6061452) and this article: [Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/).

I am new to AWS Cognito and OAuth2. I am currently using passportjs to manage my authentication and authorization the storing user sessions in DynamoDB. How can I use sessions with AWS cognito? Does AWS Cognito store session data in Cognito removing the need of using a database to store the session data?

Does this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/reduce-risk-by-implementing-httponly-cookie-authentication-in-amazon-api-gateway/) give the solution I am looking for? I have read it but have not fully understood it. I have seen it talking about JWTs.

Comment: Send the session cookie to the client, and store the session data (including who was logged in) in something like Redis.

Comment: @Evert How do I get this session cookie from Cognito to send to the client? And how do I send it to the client?

Comment: Whatever your programming language and framework of choice is, they usually have a way to setup sessions/submit cookies.